# Overflow hidden with floated children not working in Shadow DOM

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow, shadow-dom

#### Background

I'm working in a Vue environment, where I have a component with slots, which looks roughly like this:

```
<component>
    <third-party-library-element>
        <content />
    </third-party-library-element>
</component>
```

The Third-party element is not Vue based, and takes my `<content/>` and puts it into a Shadow DOM / Shadow Root

#### Issue

The issue I'm facing is that some of my `<content/>` has floated elements. Typically, `overflow:hidden` solves the issue with items running into each other, as demonstrated by this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14hq92rb/). However, when the items are added to the Shadow DOM, that no longer works. Instead, I have to place `overflow:hidden` at the `<component>` level.

The issue with putting a style at the component level is that it applies to all types of different content, and I don't want to prevent other content which I have from flowing outside its container.

Is there a way to make `overflow:hidden` work as expected when inside a Shadow DOM?

Here is the MRE, based off of the above, linked Fiddle, which shows it not working

<sub>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mgjn4w9/)</sub>

```js
function createShadowParagraphs(root) {
  root.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  
  const shadow = root.shadowRoot;
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.overflow="hidden";
  
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.style.float = "left";
  p.innerHTML = `
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
  `;
  
  shadow.appendChild(p);
}

const shadow1 = document.getElementById("shadow1");
const shadow2 = document.getElementById("shadow2");

createShadowParagraphs(shadow1);
createShadowParagraphs(shadow2);
```

```html
<div style="background:lightgreen">
  <p>This box has content that is floated</p>
  <div id="shadow1"></div>
</div>
<div style="background:lightblue;clear:left;margin-top:100px">
  <p>This box has content that is floated, but its top margin doesn't work</p>
  <div id="shadow2"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <p style="margin-top:50px">The margin on this paragraph does work because overflow hidden on the above box.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code to try and understand what you want...

But I don't understand what you want...

```html
<style>
  div { border: 1px dashed green }
</style>
<template>
  <style>
    :host { NOdisplay: inline-block }
    p { border: 2px dashed blue ; float : left }
  </style>
  <p>Hello<br />Hello<br />Hello<br /></p>
</template>
<div style="background:lightgreen">
  <p>This box has content that is floated</p>
  <div id="shadow1"></div>
</div>
<div style="background:lightblue;clear:left;margin-top:100px">
  <p>This box has content that is floated, but its top margin doesn't work</p>
  <div id="shadow2"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <p style="margin-top:50px">The margin on this paragraph does work because overflow hidden on the above box.</p>
</div>
<script>
  function createShadowParagraphs(root) {
    const div = document.createElement("div"); // this div is never used
    div.style.overflow = "hidden";
    const template = document.querySelector("template");
    root.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets AND returns root.shadowRoot
        .append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  createShadowParagraphs(shadow1); // IDs are globals, so no need for getElementById
  createShadowParagraphs(shadow2);
</script>
```

#### addition

- In your (comments) JSFidlle, you added a DIV around those floating Ps
- I uncommented `display:inline-block`

```html
<style>
  div { border: 1px dashed green }
</style>
<template>
  <style>
    :host { display: inline-block }
    p { border: 2px dashed blue ; float : left }
  </style>
  <div>
    <p>Hello<br />Hello<br />Hello<br /></p>
  </div>
</template>
<div style="background:lightgreen">
  <p>This box has content that is floated</p>
  <div id="shadow1"></div>
</div>
<div style="background:lightblue;clear:left;margin-top:100px">
  <p>This box has content that is floated, but its top margin doesn't work</p>
  <div id="shadow2"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <p style="margin-top:50px">The margin on this paragraph does work because overflow hidden on the above box.</p>
</div>
<script>
  function createShadowParagraphs(root) {
    const div = document.createElement("div"); // this div is never used
    div.style.overflow = "hidden";
    const template = document.querySelector("template");
    root.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets AND returns root.shadowRoot
        .append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  createShadowParagraphs(shadow1); // IDs are globals, so no need for getElementById
  createShadowParagraphs(shadow2);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, my first Fiddle link shows the expected end state. https://jsfiddle.net/14hq92rb/

Comment: I also see you're using `:host` styles. Because I'm inside the host, I can't target those without affecting all the other places I use the third party element.

Comment: Still not sure what you want; added a 2nd version that looks like your JSFiddle